# Windows 2008 imaging on Intel Core 2 Duo

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, restore

I have a Windows 2008 system with VMware Oracle RAC and Linux CentOS as guest OS plus Visual Studio etc installed. Can anybody tell me how do I go about creating a system image so restores can be a snap?

Comment: Is this computer part of a Windows domain?

Answer (score 1):

By installing the Windows Server Backup role via Server Manager you should be able to create a system image backup of your Windows Server 2008 machine. Be sure to include the volume that contains your virtual images of Linux and Oracle. So for example if you created the virtual machines on a partition other than the one the machine is installed on (like say E:) you would want to include E: in the recovery process. Also I would recommend backing up the server to a separate hard disk or media source so if the hard drive ever physically fails you will be able to restore your OS without any hassle.